# Return Option inside Loop

Tags: while-loop, return, rust

The program aims to use a loop to check if the index of a iterator variable meets certain criteria (i.g., index == 3). If find the desired index, return `Some(123)`, else return `None`.

```
fn main() {
    fn foo() -> Option<i32> {
        let mut x = 5;
        let mut done = false;

        while !done {
            x += x - 3;

            if x % 5 == 0 {
                done = true;
            }

            for (index, value) in (5..10).enumerate() {
                println!("index = {} and value = {}", index, value);

                if index == 3 {
                    return Some(123);
                }
            }
            return None; //capture all other other possibility. So the while loop would surely return either a Some or a None
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> <anon>:7:9
   |
7  |         while !done {
   |         ^ expected enum `std::option::Option`, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `std::option::Option<i32>`
   = note:    found type `()`
```

I think the error source might be that a while loop evaluates to a `()`, thus it would return a `()` instead of `Some(123)`. I don't know how to return a valid `Some` type inside a loop.

Comment: Strange, I cannot reproduce your error.  The code you posted compiles and runs fine for me with `rustc` version 1.12.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. I have revised the code.    I realized the error that I found is b/c I put return None inside the while loop. But the program should actually return Some(123) inside the for loop, before it can reach the return None.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of any `while true { ... }` expression is always `()`. So the compiler expects your `foo` to return an `Option<i32>` but finds the last value in your `foo` body is `()`.

To fix this, you can add a `return None` outside the original `while` loop. You can also use the `loop` construct like this:

```
fn main() {

    // run the code
    foo();

    fn foo() -> Option<i32> {
        let mut x = 5;

        loop {
            x += x - 3;

            for (index, value) in (5..10).enumerate() {
                println!("index = {} and value = {}", index, value);

                if index == 3 {
                    return Some(123);
                }
            }
            if x % 5 == 0 {
                return None;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The behaviour of `while true { ... }` statements is maybe a bit quirky and there have been a few requests to [change it.](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/allow-loops-to-return-values-other-than/567/8)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I want to make sure I really understand the problem here: Inside the while loop of my code, if nothing return a Some Type, the final "return None" would capture all other other possibility. So the while loop would surely return either a Some or a None. How can there would be still a path with no return value?

Comment: That makes tons of senses! So the difference between a loop {...} and while {...} is: loop not always return ()?

Comment: Right.  However this is a relatively recent addition.  See here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1624-loop-break-value.md